# Output Jest text coverage reporter to .txt

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, istanbul

Jest allows you to specify a coverage reporter in the package.json like so

```
{
    ...

    "jest": {
        "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
        "coverageReporters": ["json", "text", ...]
    }

    ...
}
```

However, this only outputs the `.json` summary to the coverage directory. It only prints the text version to the console. Is there a way to output the text version to a `.txt` file in the coverage folder as well?

I've been referring to the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragereporters-array-string), which says that it is compatible with any of the [Istanbul reporters](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/tree/master/lib/report). The text Istanbul reporter [appears to have support for writing to a file](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/bc84c315271a5dd4d39bcefc5925cfb61a3d174a/lib/report/text.js#L224). Is there any way to utilize it this?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the `text` coverageReporter is just an alias for `text-summary` which just goes to stdout. You can redirect it if you want, but it's an extra step and it might contain other noise: `jest --coverage > coverage/coverage.txt`

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that also contains the test results. I'm just trying to export the coverage results in the table to the `.txt`

Comment: I'm also trying to do something like this, the company I work for has a standard devops reporting platform and I need to export some of the jest test coverage stats for that

Answer (score 5):

In your jest config, you can specify the `file` option, and optionally the `dir` options which defaults to the current working directory:

```
"jest": {
  "coverageReporters": [["text", { file: 'coverage.txt' }]]
}
```

These options are mentioned briefly [in the jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options), with details in the istanbul docs [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/bc84c315271a5dd4d39bcefc5925cfb61a3d174a/lib/report/text.js#L33-L35).

Answer (score 2):

Add `json` to `coverageReports` in your jest config:
`"coverageReporters": ["json"]`

Then install istanbul:
`npm i -D istanbul`

Add this script to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {  
  "test": "jest --coverage && istanbul report --include coverage/coverage-final.json text > coverage.txt",  
  ...
}
```

The script will generate the code coverage report file `coverage-final.json` then istanbul will generate the expected output redirected to `coverage.txt`

Comment: Minor correction: npm i -D istanbul (for anybody who copy+pastes it and wonders why npm couldn't find the package... you know... people like me)

Answer (score 0):

@KerSplosh We ended up writing a custom script with `shelljs`. Basically it runs the tests, and writes the table to a file with `fs`.

```
const shell = require("shelljs");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const result = shell.exec("yarn test --coverage");
fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(".", "coverage.txt"),
    result.substring(result.indexOf("|\nFile") + 2)
);

if (result.code !== 0) {
    shell.exit(1);
}
```

This isn't ideal though. Preferably this would be done through the Jest configuration. But at the time I implemented this, I don't think it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

**If you happen to use react scripts on top of jest:**

Add these snippets to their sections in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "cover:report": "react-scripts test --coverage .> coverage/coverage-report.txt",
}
...
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
     "src/**/*.ts*"
  ],
  "coverageReporters": ["text"]
}
```

This generates coverage report in file coverage/coverage-report.txt.
The dot in ".>" part tells the script to take all files (except for ignored ones) that match the "." pattern - which would typically be all of them.

Modify the "collectCoverageFrom" array of strings to include files/folders as needed.

This command doesn't exit itself unfortunately so you have to Ctrl+C to end it when it just hangs in there after being done.

To run it in terminal: `"yarn cover:report"`

The result contains plaintext table of coverage results.